# OpenVPN client to SSH to EC2 private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I'm running the community OpenVPN server (on a CIS Level 1 RHEL 7) instance, which I can connect from my laptop without any issue. Whilst connected, I can SSH to the OpenVPN server instance using the private IP but not anything else at all. Not even a different instance in the same sub-net. Say my VPN server in: `10.100.0.0/28` subnet, VPN client subnet is: `192.168.10.0/24` and I want SSH to an instance in `10.100.0.16/28`. This is the part I have in the server config:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "route 10.100.0.16 255.255.255.240"
push "route 10.100.0.32 255.255.255.240"
;push "route 10.100.0.0 255.255.240.0"
route 10.100.0.16 255.255.255.240
route 10.100.0.32 255.255.255.240
;route 10.100.0.0 255.255.240.0
server 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

I have added these `iptables` rules to allow the VPN traffic:

```
## allow udp 1194
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -i eth0

## Allow TUN interface
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT

## Allow TUN connections to be forwarded
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## NAT the VPN client traffic to the Internet
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

## default TUN OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
```

apart from that also,

- added `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- Disabled source/destination check on the VPN instance
- added a static route to VPC route table  with **Destination:** `192.168.10.0/24`, **Target**ing the **ENI** that attached to the VPN instance
- added ingress rule in the target instances' SG to allow vpn-client subnet on port 22
- There is no NACL involved yet (but have to enable that at some point)

What else didn't do or did wrong?? I'm really stuck and know I'm missing some thing really silly. Could anyone shade some light or point me to right direction please?

-S

Comment: What happens when you attempt to connect to another instance? Do you receive an error message or does it eventually timeout? Is the security group on the target instance configured to allow such a connection?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, sorry for late reply. But I figure out, it wasn't working b'cuz of these lines: `route 10.100.0.16 255.255.255.240` and `route 10.100.0.32 255.255.255.240`in the config file. The moment I comment that out, it started working. I'm a bit confused though from the documentation on `route` and `push route`, so not really sure why those two lines were causing issue connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why it was not working. These two lines:

```
route 10.100.0.16 255.255.255.240
route 10.100.0.32 255.255.255.240
```

in the config file were causing the issue. Without those, it forwarding the traffic downstream without any issue. I'm a bit confused though from the OpenVPN documentation on `route ...` and `push "route ...`, so not really sure why those two lines were causing connection issue. So, if anyone can shade some light on that will be very much appreciated.